# Struct Array Crashing Program C

Tags: c, arrays

The program runs but every time I do it just ends up crashing it after. I also get **"Segmation Fault"** Error when running a debug

```
         enemy mob[2];

         for(i=0; i<2; i++){

            mob->mobAttack[i] = 25;
            mob->mobHealth[i] = 150;
            mob->mobName[i] = "Growler";

        }
```

Structure

```
typedef struct{

char * mobName;
int * mobHealth;
int * mobAttack;
```

} enemy;

Comment: Where in memory is the pointer `mob->mobName` pointing to?

Comment: ..and the others..

Comment: I dont know how I would allcoate memory there

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: So you know you should, right? Then what's the question?

Comment: You don't know how to allocate memory? Time to log off Stackoverflow and use your time to read a basic C book or tutorial.

Comment: You could change your struct definition so you don't need to allocate any  more memory.

Comment: How would I allcoate it though like how would i write it?

Comment: @Syntax You say C, but is it really C or is it C++ compiler and you use just C part?

Comment: I think you wanted it to be `mob[i]->mobAttack = 25;` And I also wouldn't use pointers for mobHealth and mobAttack.

Comment: @Syntax For C please look on method malloc() and free() in libraries...

Comment: Did you intend for 1 mob to have multiple health and attack values?

Comment: no I wrote the for loop to populate 3 mobs

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
    typedef struct{

    char * mobName;
    int  mobHealth;
    int  mobAttack;
} enemy
```

and

```
  mob[i].mobAttack = 25;
```

etc. I assume the compiler was complaining big time at you , dont ignore warnings

Comment: In original request it is pointer, but pm100 realized that it is unnecessary and he is right:). And provided correct code:).

Comment: Wow it worked. Thanks man!